# Google+ Javascript Signin Uncaught TypeError at cb=gapi.loaded_0:41

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-plus

I'm trying to implement a Google+ Signin on a website, following instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) for a hybrid login system. I prefer to have my own button for login, so I chose to implement the G+ signin through plain JavaScript method gapi.auth.signIn, following instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#gapi.auth.signIn).

Here's the button I have on my main page that initiates the login -

```
<a id="gplogin" href="#">
  <img src="{% static 'images/gp.png' %}"/>
</a>
```

Here's the corresponding JQuery piece that picks up the click, this is running fine too -

```
$('#gplogin').click(
  function() {
    GPLogin();
    return false;
  });
```

Here's the GPLogin() part, which is probably where it's throwing Javascript exception -

```
function GPLogin() {
    // Define all the login params
    var additionalParams = {
        'clientid' : 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'redirecturi' : 'postmessage',
        'requestvisibleactions' : 'http://schema.org/AddAction',
        'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
        'accesstype' : 'offline',
        // 'approvalprompt' : 'force',
        'callback': gpSigninCallback
    };
    console.log('Logging in to Google Plus with additional params - ');
    for(var param in additionalParams)
        console.log(param + " : " + additionalParams[param])

    gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams);
}
```

Here's my gpSigninCallback function which is never getting called, due to exception thrown when I click the 'gplogin' link

```
function gpSigninCallback(authResult) {
console.log("GP Signin response " + authResult);
for(var res in authResult)
    console.log(res + " : " + authResult[res]) }
```

The exception that is being thrown when I click on the gplogin link is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value at cb=gapi.loaded_0:41
```

as observed in Chrome.

The user selection popup comes up as expected and I can select the user, but nothing happens anywhere after that. I'm pretty sure it's a small thing I'm overlooking somewhere, but I cannot find it myself. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Just thought I should clarify, I'm loading the G+ JS API in the <head> of the page - 
`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>` 

Also, the callback param being passed as a function name/string or the function object itself is not making a difference.

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of searching around, I narrowed it down to simple Javascript error on my part. I started by commenting all the debug statements and printing the objects as-is. That is where I discovered that my callback function was getting an object for authResult[res] in one of the iterations and since I was trying to concatenate it to a String, a TypeError was being thrown.

The Google Plus Login flow was fine all the time, with my JS being the issue. It worked in GPLogin() when trying to log additionalParams[param] because they're all strings and have no problems concatenating with Strings.